# Python 2.7 pip install lxml UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-2.7, pip, lxml, python-unicode

I am trying to pip install lxml==3.3.5 on a vagrant box running Ubuntu 14.04. The error I cannot get past is below.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Using Python 2.7.6 / PIP 1.5.6 and VirtualEnv 1.11.6

After searching a bit I tried the most commonly posted solution of setting the locale (output below)

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Output of `locale -a`

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

But this yields the same error. The complete log of the build failure is available [here](http://dpaste.com/0KP5R1F). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use the `ubuntu/trusty64` box?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on Ubuntu 14.04 using the `ubuntu/trusty64` box. I can successfully build and install `lxml` in version `3.3.5`. The log of the build is available at http://paste.openstack.org/show/84586/.

Comment: I am using the cloud image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ but I will try ubuntu/trusty64 box (vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64).

Comment: Builds fine with ubuntu/trusty64 box, must have been something on the cloud-images box. Thanks Christian!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the box to `ubuntu/trusty64` fixed the issue with building lxml. I am not certain what the root cause on the cloud image was.